# Delete a directory with pipe (|) in its name?

Tags: windows-xp, pipe, directory

Without booting to Linux, how do you delete a directory that was created in Linux on an NTFS partition that contains a pipe in the file name?

For example:

```
f:\flac\foreign\Yoshida_Brothers\Best_of_Yoshida_Brothers_|_Tsugaru_Shamisen
```

Tried and failed:

- Midnight Commander
- Recursively deleting the parent folder
- `del /f /s /q Yoshida_Brothers`
- `del /f /s /q "\\?f:\flac\foreign\Yoshida_Brothers\"`
- `rmdir /s Yoshida_Brothers`
- `rmdir Best*`
- FileASSASSIN
- [Cannot delete folder](http://winhlp.com/node/39)

Other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substituting the single-character wildcard `?` for the pipe character should work:

```
del f:\flac\foreign\Yoshida_Brothers\Best_of_Yoshida_Brothers_?_Tsugaru_Shamisen
```

Comment: *.* Wont match the filename unless it has a . in the name

Comment: @DrStalker: It should under Windows. `echo hey>a & dir * & dir *.* & del *.* & dir`

Comment: @Dave: reformatting is way overkill. It's possible the file was being held open by another process. You didn't post any error messages (and I forgot to ask).

Comment: @DrStalker: Correction `Best*` did not work. The computer was freshly booted and the directory was not accessed.